# A convergent improper integral with $\int k\chi_{\{f>k\}}$ divergent

Tags: improper-integrals

If $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx\leq\infty$ , we regard it as "convergent" , does there exist such an $f$, which satisfies $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx<\infty$ , but $\int_0^{\infty}k\chi_{E_k}(x)dx$ "divergent" ?

Where $E_k=\{x:f(x)>k\}$

Well , I came to this question when I was trying to prove this

> If an improper integral of $f$ is finite, then $f<\infty$  for a.e.x.

We know that in the Lebesgue Integrals, one has **if $f$ is Lebesgue integrable then $f<\infty$ for a.e.x.**

I was trying to modifying the proof of that . Let $E_k=\{f>k\}$ , and $k\chi_{E_k}<f$ , then take the improper integral both side of the inequality , however , a problem comes , does $k\chi_{E_k}$ integrable ? Well, I just afraid of that may be a Dirichelet-like function , then that will come a "Divergent" case

Comment: Is $f$ assumed to be non-negative? Also, I think the first $\leq$ should be a $<$.

Comment: @carmichael561 Yes , when f is non-negative, then one can use the comparison principle , but $k\chi_{E_k}$ may be even nonintegrable , so I confused, I had refreshed the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got one , in the extended sense , if $f>0$ and integrable , then the improper integral exists,thus the problem is to ask if  $f$ is integrable , whether $\chi_{\{f-k>0\}}$ integrable ? 
Well, since the $f-k$ is integrable , the question is

> If $ f\geq0$ is integrable , whether $\chi_{\{f>0\}}$ is integrable ?

The answer is no, for example , the well known Riemann function $R(x)$, which is non-nagative integrable , but  $\chi_{\{R>0\}}=D(x)$  which is not integrable.

However, it won't stop me proving that result , i.e:

> the improper integral of $f$ is finite ,then $f$ is a.e finite.

For I can use $\{f\geq k\}$ to replace the original $E_k$